# Unit testing - Comparing environment

Tags: r, unit-testing

I would like to implement unit testing in R by comparing list of objects in an environment stored as rds with the current environment. I am sharing some of the codes I was trying to implement to provide an idea on what I would want

```
library(rlang)

a = FALSE
b = "a"
c = 2.3
d = 1:3


saveRDS(mget(ls()), file = "unit.rds")

# unit_t <- readRDS(file = "unit.rds")

env <- new_environment(readRDS(file = "unit.rds"))

identical(global_env(), current_env())

identical(new_environment(readRDS(file = "unit.rds")), global_env())

identical(mget(ls()), list(readRDS(file = "unit.rds")))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just at a glance, it would seem that `global_env()` contains `env`, but `unit.rds` does not, so `identical(new_environment(readRDS(file = "unit.rds")), global_env())` cannot be true. Ditto for `identical(mget(ls()), list(readRDS(file = "unit.rds")))`, `mget(ls())` will include `env`, which is not part of `unit.rds`.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas However, you'll notice commenting out that line still yields FALSE

Comment: Is it enough to compare that the **names** of the objects in each environment are the same, or do you essentially want to compare the objects themselves and return true only each pair of  objects is identical?

Comment: I would prefer the latter. I figured out the former can be achieved through identical(mget(ls()), as.list(readRDS(file = "unit.rds")))